# How can I surround my WPF Datagrid header with a curve?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I would like to surround the headers of my datagrid in WPF with a curve. My current code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Red">
        <DataGrid Height="433" x:Name="data" Width="801">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#292F3B"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightBlue"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,2,0" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#333333"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 0 0 0"/>
                    
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#20262E"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            
            
            
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="user"  Binding="{Binding user}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="User1" Binding="{Binding user1}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="User2" Binding="{Binding user2}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="User3" Binding="{Binding user3}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="User4" Binding="{Binding user4}" Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
```

I tried Corner Radius or Something else but the Property dosent find this.

Like this:[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSRO9.png)

Comment: Can you draw what you would like to see?

Comment: I edit my Question with a Picture so you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a template with a Border with rounded corners.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Border Background="Black">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1"
                            CornerRadius="6"
                            Background="LightBlue"
                            Padding="10,0,0,0"
                            Margin="2">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you it is working but at wich point could i make in this a Style.Trigger? Because i want when mouse over then a different color?

Comment: DataGridColumnHeader with such ControlTemplate is not resizable and doesn't have sorting glyph. Template is too primitive and removed a lot of default features

Comment: So there is no way to get this round and use Style.Triggers?

Comment: See this doc for a more complete style and template where you also get the resize function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/datagrid-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#datagrid-controltemplate-example
You can add triggers on the ControlTemplate for handling your mouse events.